# Is it different to use `K.constant` or `self.add_weight(trainable=False)` for fixed weights in layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom keras layer that uses a fixed weight matrix. I wonder how should I handle this fixed weight matrix using the keras API with tensorflow. In particular, why would I use `K.constant` when `self.add_weights(trainable=False)` offers more flexibility (for instance, I can use `Layer.set_weights` with the latter one).

Concretely, in the build method I can either do:

```
 class CustomLayer(Layer):
        ...

        def build(self, input_shape):
               self.fixed_tensor = K.constant(self.my_fixed_tensor)
               self.built = True
```

or

```
 class CustomLayer(Layer):
        ...

        def build(self, input_shape):
               self.fixed_tensor = self.add_weight(
                    shape=self.my_fixed_tensor.shape,
                    initializer=lambda shape, dtype: self.my_fixed_tensor,
                    trainable=False
               )
               self.built = True
```

Both solutions work, I wonder if they are handled differently in the backend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`K.constant`](https://keras.io/backend/#constant) is simply the Keras analogous to [`tf.constant`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), it just creates a constant-valued tensor. It is a lower-level construct and, like you say, it is useful only for values that will never change. Most times it is not necessary to call this explicitly, as doing something like `2 * my_tensor` will convert the `2` into a constant 
tensor with the right type automatically for you. However, in some cases you may prefer to call it explicitly, for example if you have an array of constant values and only want a single tensor representing them (instead of repeatedly converting them into new constant tensors).

`add_weight` is a method for layers, and it creates a TensorFlow variable representing some mutable value in the layer. Weights are a higher-level concept, related to layered models. As you point out, weights, trainable or not, can be changed dynamically.

In theory, you could have absolutely no constants in a model and replace them all with weights. However, it is generally not very practical, as variables, at least in 1.x, need to be initialized, their use cannot be optimized as well as with constants and their overhead would not give you any benefit if you are never changing it.